# Splitting and filtering the output of linux command in perl

Tags: linux, perl, awk

I'm creating a perl script to run on a PABX system that returns the status of the SIP trunks. I'm very new to perl and want to create a script using the output from the following command

```
/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx "sip show registry"
```

Returns the following output

```
Host            dnsmgr   Username     Refresh  State        Reg.Time                 
x.x.x.x:5060    N        02xxxxxxxx   105      Registered   Thu, 28 Aug 2014 06:34:21
1 SIP registrations.
```

I want to filter the username field and get the state field, I can do this easily at the command line with the following command but having trouble working out the best way of doing it in perl. Also which is best practice, using perl functions or passing data back to programs like grep and awk?

```
/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx "sip show registry" | awk '/02xxxxxxxx/ {print $5}'
```

which returns whatever in the state column, in this example it returns

```
Registered
```

I then want to compare the state in an if statement and perform an action depending on the state, this bit seems easy enough though.

In this example there is only 1 SIP trunk, but there could be many.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Perl functions is faster and easier to debug.

```
open my $AST, '-|', '/usr/sbin/asterisk', '-rx', 'sip show registry' or die $!;
while (<$AST>) {
    print +(split)[4], "\n" if /02xxxxxx/;
}
```

Or, a bit more verbose:

```
open my $AST, '-|', '/usr/sbin/asterisk', '-rx', 'sip show registry' or die $!;
while (my $line = <$AST>) {
    if ($line =~ /02xxxxxx/) {
        my @items = split ' ', $line;
        print $items[4], "\n" ;
    }
}
```

Read more:
[open](http://p3rl.org/open), 
[print](http://p3rl.org/print),
[split](http://p3rl.org/split),
[Perl syntax](http://p3rl.org/perlsyn).

Comment: are you able to provide the above code broken down into the key components such as the split, print and if statement instead of the optimised one-liner version, it will help me understand better. Thanks

Comment: @choroba Do you know what version of perl this multiple parameter form of open was enabled?  Seems it isn't in 5.12 but is in 5.18.  Also, could you briefly explain the benefits?  I believe I already know some benefits, but would appreciate your experience.

Comment: @Miller: Works for me even in 5.10, should work in 5.8.x too. It might not work on MSWin, though (see [open](http://p3rl.org/open)). The main benefit is correct shell quoting (same as with [system](http://p3rl.org/system)).